# d3.js - need help debugging differences in Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am experimenting with this [d3 demo](http://enjalot.github.com/intro-d3/costofliving/) and I am having trouble debugging why I am experiencing different behavior in Chrome vs. Safari/FireFox. If I run the **full code** below, it works in Chrome but not in Safari/Firefox. I seem to have isolated the problem to the following:

If I change this line:

```
var circles = chart.select("#points").selectAll("circle")
```

to this:

```
var circles = chart.selectAll("circle")
```

it works in Safari/Firefox/Chrome, but I want to understand what is happening and why the code below doesn't work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Full Code**

```
 <svg>
  <g id="chart">
   <g id="bg">
   </g>
   <g id="countries">
   </g>
   <g id="points">
   </g>
  </g>
 </svg>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  d3.json("costofliving.json", function(col) {

    var cx = 200;
    var cy = 132;

    var cw = 400;
    var ch = 400;

    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var nticks = 14;

    var price_min = 0;
    var price_max = d3.max(col, function(d) {return d.price});

    var rent_min = 0;
    var rent_max = d3.max(col, function(d) {return d.rent});

    var price_scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([price_min, price_max])
      .range([ch, 0]);
    var rent_scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([rent_min, rent_max])
      .range([0, cw]);

    var price_layout = d3.layout.histogram()
      .value(function(d) { return d.price })
      .range([0, price_max])
      .bins(nticks);

    var rent_layout = d3.layout.histogram()
     .value(function(d) { return d.rent })
     .range([0, rent_max])
     .bins(nticks);

   var chart = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + [cx, cy] + ")");

  chart.append("g")
   .attr("id", "countries")
   .style("opacity", 0);

  chart.append("g")
   .attr("id", "points")

  var circles = chart.select("#points").selectAll("circle")
   .data(col);

  circles.enter()
   .append("circle")

  circles.attr({
    r: 6,
    cx: function(d,i) {
    return rent_scale(d.rent);
   },
    cy: function(d,i) {
    return price_scale(d.price);
   }
  })  
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Which Chrome, Safari and Firefox verions are you using? I guess the latest but in any case :)

Comment: Safari 5.1.7; Firefox 16.0.2; Chrome 23

Comment: The http://enjalot.github.com/intro-d3/costofliving/ website does not work in my Firefox 17. And is very unresponsive at first when loading in my Chrome 23. Maybe the problem is related to the tributary stuff? This also seems to be broken in my FF.
Btw: where do I get the `costofliving.json`. I can only see a csv.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There is the `costofliving.json` in this demo: http://enjalot.com/tributary/3714774/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a `width` and `height` for any `svg` element in Firefox. According to the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElementWidthAttribute), the svg element will use "100%" as default, but my Firefox 17 (and probably other browsers) may not yet implement it like that.

When setting some absolute values in your code it works as expected.

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
```

Comment: It's not a bug. Read https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668163 for the whole complicated story of why not.

Comment: OMG that is really complicated. I guess the W3C need to change the spec. ;)