# D3.js transition bug in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/EyrRD/. I use D3.js library to animate SVG rectangle by changing its width:

```
rect.transition().duration(2000).delay(500).ease("cubic-out").attr("width", 500);​
```

Everything works fine in other browsers, but in Firefox animation suddenly stops when rectangle width reaches 300px. Actually it doesn't matter what is the destination width (>=300), it always stops at 300px. Is that really a bug? If so, how to overcome this? An by the way, is D3.js the best tool for this kind of SVG animations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568915/firefox-not-displaying-svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `width` of the SVG:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000);
```

In Firefox and maybe other browsers you need to set a width and height for the svg:svg element. It is a Firefox bug, here is my related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527125/d3-js-need-help-debugging-differences-in-chrome-safari-and-firefox/13532842#13532842).

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried to set the SVG width "by hand" (by adding style param to svg elem) and it didn't change anything, so I assumed the problem is somewhere else. Do you think D3.js is the best tool for SVG manipulation?

Comment: Yes I think d3 is the best, regarding ease of use AND performance.

Comment: It's not a bug. Expect other browsers to require this in future.

Comment: OK it's a feature ;) - Thanks for pointing [that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668163) out.